# Android - How to use an ImageView in a SplashScreen

Tags: android, imageview, splash-screen

My company has a single activity Android Kotlin applicaiton.
We would like to display a splashscreen on startup.
After reading a bunch of turtorial I have found a way to do it.
But when I try to display an `ImageView` the splashscreen, it becomes a white background.

Here is my code:

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreen">
    ...
</application
```

#### Theme.SplashScreen in res/values/themes/themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <style name="Theme.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
    </style>
    ...
</resources>
```

#### res/drawable/splash_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item>

        <!-- This works
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        -->
        <!-- This doesn't work --> 
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_somePicture"
            app:tint="@color/white" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Notice I have **two** cases here: The `bitmap` and the `ImageView` cases.

- The `bitmap` case work if I uncomment it.
  During startup this image is displayed in the splashscreen.
- The `ImageView` case doesn't work.
  This result is a completely white splashscreen.

The `ImageView` "should" work, because I use the same setup in some fragments.

The `@drawable/ic_somePicture` is a SVG-image that I have added in the AndroidStudio project.
I cannot show it here, as it's a property of my company.
Notice I have to specify the `app:tint` property to show the image on whatever background color I have in either the `splash_background.xml` or the fragment.

What could be the problem?
Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Start with using the same resource as with the bitmap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tint bitmap in layer-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524697/tint-bitmap-in-layer-list)

Comment: I tried this:

`<bitmap
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_respondersplashlogo"
            android:tint="@color/red">
        </bitmap>`
But it didn't work.
Also the preview in the designer will only preview if I use the `@mipmap/ic_launcher`.

Comment: As I understand it, ImageViews aren't allowed in @drawables

Answer (score 0):

I have this setting in my SplashScreen

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    private val SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 5000
    override fun onCreate(s: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(s)
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Handler().postDelayed({ /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            val mainIntent = Intent()
            mainIntent.setClass(applicationContext, MapsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(mainIntent)
            finish()
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH.toLong())
    }
}
```

ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/image_splash"/>
```